# How to load a new page and pass data from api?

Tags: angularjs

I have page with list of teams. On click I need title and members of that team on another page. I just loaded teams in the list. Code is here:

```
angular.module('my-app').controller('MainController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://...").success(function(response) {
        $scope.details = response;          
    });
});
```

and

```
<article ng-app="seed-angular">
    <section ng-controller="MainController as mc">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in details">
                <a href="/team/team.html">{{x.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>        
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: are you using a router in your app?  Typically your `href` wouldn't point to a unique html document, it would point to a route in your app that loads the new content.  Angular is a Single Page Application framework, and pointing to a new html page is actually going to mean you have more than one angular application (one application per page), which *can* work, but isn't really efficient.  see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route or the 3rd party state provider https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Also (not related to the question at hand) you are mixing syntax here, which doesn't have an impact now but could be troublesome if your code becomes more complex.  You are using the ControllerAs syntax (`MainController as mc`) which is designed to be used *instead* of directly binding to `$scope`, which is what `$scope.details` is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Claies, you need to use a router in your app. From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07):

> Application routes in Angular are declared via the `$routeProvider`, which is the provider of the `$route` service. This service makes it easy to wire together controllers, view templates, and the current URL location in the browser. Using this feature, we can implement [deep linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking), which lets us utilize the browser's history (back and forward navigation) and bookmarks.

There are some libraries in which you can do that. I'll use [`ngRoute`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) as an example as it comes with Angular.js.

To do so, you need to add the `angular-route.js` and load the `ngRoute` module:

```
var app = angular.module('seed-angular', [
  'ngRoute'
]);
```

You also need to configure your `$routeProvider` to setup your URL routes, like this:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/team', {
      templateUrl: 'team-list.html',
      controller: 'MainController'
    }).
    when('/team/:teamId', {
      templateUrl: 'team-detail.html',
      controller: 'TeamDetailController'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/team'
    });
  }
]);
```

In the routes above, we've configured `/team` to route to a template page `team-list.html`. Note that the `<a href="">` now passes a parameter `teamId`:

```
<article>
    <section ng-controller="MainController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in details">
                <a href="#/team/{{x._id}}">{{x.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>        
    </section>
</article>
```

We also configured `/team/:teamId` to route to a template page `team-detail.html` (note that `:teamId` [means it's a parameter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)):

```
<article>
  <section ng-controller="TeamDetailController">
    <a href="#/teams">Back</a>
    <div ng-repeat="x in details">
      <strong>{{x._id}}</strong>
      <ul>
        <li>
          {{x.firstName}} {{x.lastName}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</article>
```

In which you will be able to access `teamId` via `$routeParams.teamId` to retrieve the team details:

```
app.controller('TeamDetailController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  var url = "http://est-teams.estudent.hr/api/teams/" + $routeParams.teamId + "/members";
  $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
    $scope.details = response;
  });
});
```

---

See this [fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/00k9rA?p=preview) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass the data you can create service and create function that store or set your data, then call it in your first controller that called the data and call it again in your next page controller here is the code :

this is the service :

```
myApp.service('sharedProperties', function() {
    var stringValue = 'test string value';
    var objectValue = {
        data: 'test object value'
    };

    return {
        getString: function() {
            return stringValue;
        },
        setString: function(value) {
            stringValue = value;
        },
        getObject: function() {
            return objectValue;
        }
    };
});
```

you can call it in your controller like this :

```
myController.controller('UserUpdateController', ['$scope', '$http','sharedProperties',
    function($scope, $http, sharedProperties ) {
        $scope.updateUser = function() {
        .....
            id = sharedProperties.getString();


        };

    }
]);
```

and set the data from your previous page like this :

```
myController.controller('UserListController', ['$scope', '$http','sharedProperties',
    function($scope, $http, sharedProperties) {


        $scope.updateUser = function(id){
            console.log("from index "+id);
            sharedProperties.setString(id);
        };


    }
]);
```